# How to add file extensions in CLOC(Count lines of code)

Tags: cloc

Am using cloc to count lines of code. There are 140 files are getting ignored as there BIN and esql files are there. How do I make cloc to read these files? How to read files with extensions like bin and esql?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy6Bs.png)

Comment: Please add details to your question. Please also add more tags to identify the product that esql relates to.

Answer (score 1):

You can include files of unrecognized type by using the `--include-ext` option. In your case, assuming the files have a .esql extension:

`cloc --include-ext=esql .`

Further, cloc has the option `--read-binary-files`, but the man page warns that this is usually a bad idea.

Check `man cloc` for more information on the man page.